# How to always show milliseconds when parsing datetime with chrono in rust?

Tags: datetime, rust, datetime-format

I am trying to format a [`chrono::NaiveDate`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDate.html) like this: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.f`

According to the third example in the [documentation](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDateTime.html#example-4) I expected this to work like so:

```rust
use chrono::NaiveDate;

fn main() {
    let date = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2015, 7, 1).and_hms_milli(0, 0, 0, 0);
    println!("{}", date.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.f"));
}
```

However instead of the desired output `2015-07-01T00:00:00.000` this prints `2015-07-01T00:00:00`.

[Rust Playground is here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f1392e9f277ba3142eac16a157debac3)

Apparently the milliseconds only get included, if they are not zero:

```rust
use chrono::NaiveDate;

fn main() {
    let date = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2015, 7, 1).and_hms_milli(0, 0, 0, 1);
    println!("{}", date.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.f"));
}
```

is there an option to always include them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.3f` as the last specifier](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/format/strftime/index.html#specifiers). This is similar to `.%f` *but left-aligned but fixed to a length of 3*

```
println!("{}", date.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.3f"));
```